# What are methods to detect, prevent and manage errors during TCP connection in Java?

Tags: java, networking, tcp

Well, I have Java SE server app, which accepts connections at ServerSocket and creates Threads for managing connections with clients.

Basically the protocol is as follows: one client sends request, then another client sends request, then server processes both requests and gives response to both clients (different responses). Then the whole process repeats indefinitely (until server decides to end session). The connection is kept alive until the end of session.

So, what is the best method (or any method at all) to detect lost connection (at both sides, server and client) and restore it if necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some kind of heartbeat mechanism to periodically send a small data packet from one end to the other and the other end should respond with something. If you don't receive a response after some amount of time, disconnect and have both ends set to try to reconnect (or listen for new connection) when this happens.